how to record pcap file in omnet ++
i recorded the pcap file but it was empty, here is code ini file :
*.hostB.numPcapRecorders = 1
*.hostB.pcapRecorder[0].typename = "PcapRecorder"
*.hostB.pcapRecorder[0].pcapFile = "results/hostvictim.pcap"
*.hostB.pcapRecorder[0].pcapLinkType = 105
it suppose to give pcap file not empty , so now i dont knew what the problem, why pcap file is empty.
